# How to retrieve top 3 results for each column in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, postgresql-9.3

I have given a question. 
The table looks like this..

```
STATE          | year1 | ... | year 10
AP             | 100   | ... | 120
assam          | 13    | ..  | 42
madhya pradesh | 214   | ... | 421
```

Now, I need to get the top - 3 states for each year.

I tried everything possible. But, I am not able to filter results per column.

Comment: You have a design problem. Enumerated columns are mostly a sign of bad design.

Comment: Well, I didn't implement this design, I have referred to this website for this dataset. https://data.gov.in/catalog/stateut-wise-accidents-caused-due-intake-alcoholdrugs-and-exceeding-lawful-speed-drivers

Comment: Could you please share your schema definition like this:
table A
column state: text
column year1: integer 
and so on or otherwise but with detailed explanation. And provide an example with some input and expected output from query.

Comment: I am not even sure with the output myself.

Comment: Detailed explanation as in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a design problem. The enumerated column are almost always a sign of bad design.

For now you could unpivot using `unnest` and then use window function `row_number` to get the top 3 states per year:

```
with unpivoted as (
    select state,
        unnest(array[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]) as year,
        unnest(array[
            year_1, year_2, year_3, 
            year_4, year_5, year_6, 
            year_7, year_8, year_9, 
            year_10
            ]) as value,
    from your_table
    )
select *
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over (
            partition by year 
            order by value desc
            ) as seqnum
    from unpivoted t
    ) t 
where seqnum <= 3;
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/WBEGI41601)

Comment: What does t.* specify? Can you explain the solution?

Comment: @Sunil It means select all columns from table with alias t

Comment: I didn't understand the double select statements written there.